# EntityQuery using jsonResultsAdapter

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to use breeze EntityQuery with jsonResultsAdapter to consume a third party API like this (DataService setup omitted):

```
var jsonResultsAdapter = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
            name: "eventAdapter",
            extractResults: function (json) {
                return json.results;
            },
            visitNode: function (node, queryContext, nodeContext) {
                var entityTypeName = 'Event';
                var entityType = entityTypeName && queryContext.entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityTypeName, true);
                var propertyName = nodeContext.propertyName;
                var ignore = propertyName && propertyName.substr(0, 1) === "$";

                return {
                    entityType: entityType,
                    nodeId: node.$id,
                    nodeRefId: node.$ref,
                    ignore: ignore
                };
            }
        });

var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("Events")
                .using(jsonResultsAdapter);

        return this.manager.executeQuery(query);
```

But it's returning this error: "**Cannot read property '$type' of null**"

I think that the EntityManager is ignoring the *.using(jsonResultAdapter)* statement and it's trying to use the default jsonResultsAdapter defined at breeze.js:

```
ctor.prototype.jsonResultsAdapter = new JsonResultsAdapter({

    name: "webApi_default",

    visitNode: function (node, queryContext, nodeContext ) {
        var entityTypeName = EntityType._getNormalizedTypeName(node.$type);
        var entityType = entityTypeName && queryContext.entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityTypeName, true);
        var propertyName = nodeContext.propertyName;
        var ignore = propertyName && propertyName.substr(0, 1) === "$";

        return {
            entityType: entityType,
            nodeId: node.$id,
            nodeRefId: node.$ref,
            ignore: ignore
        };
    }
```

Don't know how to tell breeze to use my jsonResultsAdapter instead default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **v 1.2.7**, this has been fixed.

----- previous post

Ok, that's a bug. It will be fixed in the next release.

For now, I think you can use the dataService's jsonResultsAdapter instead.  i.e. something like this.

```
var ds = new DataService( { serviceName: yourServiceName, jsonResultsAdapter: yourAdapter });
var em = new EntityManager({ dataService: ds });
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("Events")
return em.executeQuery(query);
```